# Error with AndroidSdk Chart using MPAndroid

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
Error:(48, 19) error: constructor BarData in class BarData cannot be applied to given types;
required: IBarDataSet[]
found: ArrayList<String>,BarDataSet
reason: varargs mismatch; ArrayList<String> cannot be converted to IBarDataSet
```

This is the error that pops out in my androidask project that supose to make a basic Chart, Im using MPAndroidChart 2.2.4 as lybrary, I have androidsdk 2.2.1 and this is the part of the code where this error leads:

```
    BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Dates");
    BarData theData;

    theData = new BarData(theDates,barDataSet);
```

And this is the tutarial that showed me how to make this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pi1tq-bp7uA

As allways sorry for bad english, and I hope to get an anser as soon as pasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BarData` constructor accepts `IBarDataSet` instead of `BarDataSet` that you have been passing. 
Try this way:

```
IBarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(barEntries,"Dates");
BarData theData;

theData = new BarData(theDates,barDataSet);
```

Comment: Still the same error, but i found this part in the [meta]build.grade code:
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'
    compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')
If i change the v3.0.1 in the 2nd line to v2.2.4 a different error apires

Comment: Found what in build.gradle?

Comment: wath the first 3 min of the tutorial,its around 1:40

Comment: You dont need this line

Comment: compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')

Comment: Remove `compile files('libs/mpandroidchartlibrary-2-2-4.jar')` from `build.gradle` and try again

Comment: Thx i just remuved all the things that i added to the build.grade and it workes perfecty

Comment: No problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the newest version (3.0.0-beta1) of [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)?

The constructor of this class has changed:

```
public BarData(List<IBarDataSet> dataSets) {
    super(dataSets);
}
```